# MapKit Pin drop

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit

I wanna make an iPhone application with map that will have few pins in it.. Can someone please just add one or two pins in my project so that I can see how to do that.. I've tried to do that with few tutorials, but I don't get it where to put the code.. =/

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use an [`MKPinAnnotationView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkpinannotationview). The [MapCallouts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mapkit_annotations/annotating_a_map_with_custom_data?language=objc) demo project has some example uses of it. Look at the `MapViewController.m` file, specifically the `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` method.

Comment: MapCallouts now redirects to AnnotatingAMapWithCustomData. I've fixed the broken link, but I believe it's now in Swift, so `MapViewController.m` may not be relevant anymore.